# Re-open request for question 312922

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, reopen-request

[What Can I do to Improve Cable Link/Signal Quality?](https://superuser.com/questions/312922/what-can-i-do-to-improve-cable-link-signal-quality)

The author specifically mentions that he has internet connection problems due to this issue.  Finally, I present this clause from the [SuperUser FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) in regards to questions which are *not* allowed:

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except
>   insofar as they interface with your computer**

So, I would suggest this question be re-opened, as it is a valid issue pertaining to computer hardware (the author is seeking a way to improve the signal quality delivered to his hardware cable modem).

Comment: Don't see why it would be off topic. In the end it's about making your home network faster. It might only be that there aren't that many people who know a definitive answer as stuff like this is beyond most home user's experience. The question might still be a bit vague though.

Comment: Reopened so far to see if it gets better in terms of information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)

Comment: +1 so it's not considered unanswered.

Comment: Accepted for completeness, thanks Jeff!